# Disable HTML based scrolling webview javafx

Tags: javafx, webview, scroll

Im using a custom webview to display my text i made with htmleditor.
The custom webview adjusts the size of the webview so the text fits almost perfectly in it.
I make the webview "throw"  its scrollEvent to the scrollpane with vbox in it it, so its not handled by the webview itself.
But still i see the text scroll up and down a bit inside the custom webview when i scroll over it. I read on some other post its the HTML itself that handles the scrolling. But i have no idea how to disable that.

```
   webView.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {

            vBox.getOnScroll().handle(scrollEvent);
            scrollEvent.consume();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for what I understood you don´t want the scrollbar to move your page

Set the scroll bar invisible

```
scrollBar.setVisible(false);
```

Disable the scrollbar, so on move the event won´t happen

```
scrollPane.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL,new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
        if (event.getDeltaX() != 0) {
            event.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

Or you can use scroll panes, and set them to fit.

```
scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
```

Hope any of these would help.

Comment: Thanks for replying , but it doesnt fix my problem. the webview is not inside a scrollpane . its inside a VBox , and that VBox is in a scrollpane. I let the scrollpane handle the scrollevent, but i still see the weppage move a bit itself when i scroll the scrollpane

Comment: @BetaBen I would need to see a source code, if you upload on gitlab functional program with the problem I can download it and do something with it.

Comment: im not familiar with gitlab. I took a look at there site but got a bit lost on it. How do i post code there?

Comment: @BetaBen,  can you find your answer?